# Spelling of "possibility"

Tags: orthography

I looked up [possibility](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/possible) on Thesaurus.com,

but what I want to know is where the 'i' in possibility comes from?

Why not have 'possibile' or 'possiblity'?

Comment: Because. Really, that's the entire answer. There is no secret cabal of English Gods who are actively designing and dictating the language, no one is reviewing it to make sure it's self-consistent or logical ... in short, there is no governance. There is no "why"; language, like a tree, simply grows, and tiny accidents of history can result in long, twisty branches leading nowhere. It is spelled as it is spelled. Accept it and move on.

Comment: Not that I have the answer, @DanBron, but I have a hard time accepting "because" as an answer, either.  There is a reason or history for the peculiarity of how a word is spelled.  OP's not asking "why", he's asking where it comes from.

Comment: How is *possibility* an exception, or any different from several other such "anomalies"? Or, is the OP using the word as a class-example?

Comment: @LittleEva No, they got their tongues twisted way too much, rather.

Comment: poss**ible**---> possibility; respons**ible**---> responsibility; desira**ble**---> desiribility; gull**ible**---> gullibility. the **-ity** is a common [suffix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ity).

Comment: Well, folks, I was just playing. I looked at Mr. Perry's bio and he mentions that he's a humorous guy and I thought he might be having fun. But if the question is sincere I think he, like everyone else, is deserving of a sincere and informed response, a response I'm not capable of providing. And @Kristina Lopez, I would guess that you are right and that most of the time there are valid reasons why we have the spelling as we have it, and often there's a record of development. Surely one or two of our scholars will know.

Comment: @LittleEva, Mari-Lou A, Kris, Dan Bron, I have given you guys an answer below. Feel free to enjoy! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez You're exactly right. Your comment spurred me on to write an answer ... You can find it below! :-)

Comment: @Araucaria I enjoyed it, but had to down vote it. That's not the point of the question, or the answer to it really.

Comment: @Kris No probs:) I think it is though - although I might be wrong. Why do you feel it's not? (I might be able to improve my answer ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is this: the word *possible* has three syllables. In the transcription /pɒsɪbl̩/, we can see a little mark under the /l/ which indicates that that the /l/ constitutes a whole syllable on its own. There is an alternative, slightly child-like pronunciation for this word, /pɒsɪbəl/. This uses the schwa vowel before the /l/ to make the nucleus of the final syllable (we can think of the nucleus like the body of the syllable).

Syllabic /l/, like syllabic /n/ is only found in unstressed syllables like this. There is nearly always an alternative pronunciation available with a schwa vowel, /ə/ instead. Schwa, like syllabic /n/ and syllabic /l/, also only occurs in unstressed syllables.

Now, here's the point. The suffix *-ity*, which is used to change adjectives into nouns, involves a stress rule. It dictates that the stress in the word occurs on the previous syllable. In other words the stress must move to the last syllable of the root word. This kind of stress rule is very common with suffixes in English. For example, the suffix *-tion* dictates that the stress moves to the previous syllable in exactly the same way. We can see the stress move when we add the suffixes to the following examples (stress is indicated by **bold** font):

- con'**tam**inate.
- contami'**na**tion.
- ab'**nor**mal.
- abnor'**mal**ity.

This rule causes an issue with certain adjectives, however. The following words are usually said with a syllabic /l/ at the end:

- ac**cess**ible
- re**li**able
- de**ni**able
- res**pon**sible.

Now if we want to stick the suffix *-ity* onto the ends of these words to make nouns, our rule says that the final syllable of the original adjective must now be stressed. However, we can't do this because we cannot have a stressed syllable in English that is a syllabic consonant. If you try to say:

- possi**ble**ity

You will immediately notice that this sounds very odd - because it breaks the phonological rules of English. One solution to this is to put a vowel in the final syllable of the root. We can't however use a schwa, because as we noted above, schwa cannot occur in stressed syllables in English either. The solution to this problem is to insert the KIT vowel /ɪ/ in the final syllable. This allows us to put the stress on the correct syllable:

- accessi'**bil**ity
- relia'**bil**ity
- denia'**bil**ity
- responsi'**bil**ity

This is the sound being represented by the letter 'I'. Now that we have a stressable syllable here, everything is now ok with the <del>world</del> - sorry, I meant *word*.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: +1 That was great instruction, though because it's all new to me it raised some new questions relating to your terminology. I could grasp the reasoning though. Thank you.

Comment: i just looked up 'possibility' on a phonetic dictionary:http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?in=possibility&stress=-s (i was looking for one that made noises)

Comment: @LittleEva Feel free to ask any questions. I'm quite happy to answer anything you might be wondering about. (It might help me improve the post too!)

Comment: This only gives half the answer, though: it explains why it's not _possiblity_, but not why it's not _possibile_. There's no synchronic reason the phonemic schwa (or phonemic syllabic l if you believe in those) couldn't be represented orthographically by _-ile_ the way it is in _nubile_, _mobile_,  and _labile_ (when not pronounced to rhyme with _bile_). The real answer to that is, as Roger points out, that the unstressed vowel was lost in Old French, and English has taken the OF spelling directly without modifying it, for both adjective and noun.

Comment: i just got 'noble' -> 'nobility', so 'le' -> 'ility', but 'mobile' would then go to 'mobiility'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Almost:) In *noble*, the last syllable goes from "*ble*", /bl/, to "***bil***" /bɪl/ for the word 'nobility'. We than have the stressable syllable in the root,'*bil*', and the suffix, '*-ity*'. The silent *e* at the end of *ble* gets dropped , and the /I/ is inserted into the /bl/ so it can be stressed. So that's exactly correct. It's all because /bl/ doesn't have a real vowel that we need to add the /ɪ/.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry (... continued) In *mobile*, however, we don't need to insert any extra vowel, because the last syllable already contains a proper stressable vowel: *bile*, /baɪl/.  This is a proper syllable which has a full vowel. There is no syllabic consonant here, so all we need to do is add the suffix *-ity* /ɪti/ onto the root. So we just drop the silent E and add the suffix 'ity': '*mobil*' + '*ity*': /məʊ'**bɪl**ɪti/. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

In some respect your question is justified as the Latin adjective is pos'sibilis/possibile, the French form is aready shortened pos'sible and English has the French form but the stress on the first syllable 'possible.
The Latin noun possi'bilitas/ possibili'tat-is (genitive) gives possibili'té in French and possi'bility in English.

Link to etymonline possible and possibility

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=possible&searchmode=none

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=possibility&searchmode=none

Comment: +1 A link to a reliable source of etymology would help, too.